# Latex cutting off figures because of white space

Tags: pdftex, crop, white-space

Now I've seen variations of this question but none of them solve my issue.

Latex is cropping my figure's legend because it is on the right of the image so I suppose it has too much "white space" (?).

```
\section*{Problem 1}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\vspace*{2mm}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=4in]{Q1/TOA Energy Balance.pdf}   
\end{center}
\caption{xxx}
\end{figure}
```

I tried shifting my image to the left with \hspace but it was still cropped on the right so that's not the issue[image]. I'm attaching what the Latex file looks like now. You can see on the right the left side of the legend box.
Does anyone have a way of making latex keep the original size of an image?

As a side issue, do you know how to remove the "Energy balance.pdf" from being printed?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  to get rid of white space around the graphic, you can use the external tppl `pdfcrop`.  the, to get rid of the printed line at the top, look for the `clip` or `crop` option of `\includegraphics`.  not able to test at the moment.

Comment: What happens if you either leave off the `width` option or if you state it as `width=\textwidth`? Separately, how did you create the PDF file that contains the graph? Did maybe some kind of truncation of the legend boxes happen at that stage?

Comment: @Mico the images are right out of python. They look fine when opening on preview and haven't been cropped at any step in the process until putting into latex. I tried putting     width=\textwidth    but the result is the same :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Image cropping

The best strategy also depends on the image type:

- If the image is a *bitmap*, it can be extracted by `pdfimages`. Then, the result
  can be edited in an image manipulation program (`gimp` and others) to remove
  the margins and to export in a lossless format like PNG.
- In case of a *vector graphics*, the PDF file can be cropped by `pdfcrop` for instance.

### Partial file name leak

`Energy Balance.pdf` is the part of the image file name after the first space.
Package `grffile` adds support for spaces in image file names (depending on the
driver) and the leaked file name part should be gone.

Comment: Thanks for the partial file name leak solution, but I'm not sure the image cropping is the right solution as I'm looking to find a way for Latex NOT to crop it at all (right now it's cropping the legends).

Comment: @JadeChee For an analysis of the "crop" problem, a correct [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and the included image file would be useful/needed.